# Upload/update Website by E-Mail

Tags: php, email, upload, web

I tried to search for this problem, but there are alway things like "i don't recomment to use E-Mail for that", and then there are other solutions. So, I'm here and ask u:

I need a way to upload/generate files(.html/.php) on my Website via E-Mail. And it realy need to be E-Mail, because E-Mail will be the only possible way for me to communicate(google: winlink) with the internet in the next month/year.
But I have no idea how i could do this. I'm looking here for some ideas/ways/tipps for what i should look, or better a good and ready solution.

It should be possible to send a E-Mail with a text, and this needs to be placed in a .html or .php file on my webspace. And good would be, if I'm able to give the name of the file ... and then replace or generate it.

I hope there is a solution in php ... but if sql is necessary it ok too(I'm going to learn it next, too).

MfG Torben

Answer (score 0):

If you have the opportunity to setup a mail server, you can handle stuff like this with some effort with sieve (depending on subject, content or from address) and dovecot. Here's a tutorial in german for setting up a mail server: [Mail-Server](https://thomas-leister.de/internet/mailserver-ubuntu-server-dovecot-postfix-mysql/)

Once setup, you can write a program which is called by sieve and is running the code required for what you desire. Please note carefully that this will never be

a) save

b) failure prove

If you can live with those side effects, feel free to go with it!

SIDENOTE:

Better solution might be: Wherever you have access to the internet, you can access the internet and your site/server to.

Comment: Thx for first answer. But I dont want to set up a own mailserver(or I'm not sure what u mean with that) ... i have rent webspace and I'm hosting a website there. I know, that it is possible to install WordPress onto it and there is a function like that uncluded(to blog via e-mail), but i realy dont want to us WordPress.

Comment: And u said " Better solution might be: Wherever you have access to the internet, you can access the internet and your site/server to."  - Yes, wherever I have internet I can acces my site by ftp, BUT i will NOT have internet. Maybe for some that sounds ridiculous, but there is a way to send E-Mail with no internet ;) ... (because i knew that some think like that, i gave the hint above: winlink).

Answer (score 0):

For the WinLink and Sailmail community, [SailBlog](http://www.sailblogs.com/) offers a blog web space, which is editable via E-Mail. This feature is integrated to the GUI of Airmail (WinLink client for PACTOR, Telnet, Packet and also WINMOR using BPQ32 TCP/IP virtual serial port emulation). Sadly, the Post By Email feature requires an Premium Basic account.

But what about setting up a new E-Mail account, looking for a Perl or PHP library that can handle E-Mail and MIME attachments and running a script on your server, which checks for new E-Mails (new Upload files, directory listing request, Upload files etc.)